# conversing mp4 to wav with the same file name in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wav, mp4, pyffmpeg

Below are my code and I am trying to convert `mp4` file to `wav` with some parameter change, like I am changing its frequency and so on. Now my problem is I have 100 `mp4` files in the `"inputdir"` folder and I read the file one by 1 and convert it, then I want to save the file with the same name as `mp4` file names but with different extension(in my case `.wav`). In my above code, every time I am converting, it's getting saved as out.wav. Can some one suggest me some options please?

I also checked [How do I use FFMPEG to create a WAV file with the same name as the input (m4a) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236053/how-do-i-use-ffmpeg-to-create-a-wav-file-with-the-same-name-as-the-input-m4a-f)

but I don't find any answer.

Thanks :)

```
import os
import ffmpy

inputdir = '/home/------my folder path------------'


for filename in os.listdir(inputdir):
    actual_filename = filename[:-4]
    if(filename.endswith(".mp4")):
        os.system("ffmpeg -i {0} -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 out.wav".format(filename))
    else:
        continue
```

I want to make it as,

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i {0} -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 actual_filename.wav".format(filename))
```

I also tried like below.

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i "$filename" -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 "${actual_filename}".wav".format(filename))
```

But it does not work. I am getting

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i "$filename" -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 "${actual_filename}".wav".format(filename))
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing your quotes in the `os.system` call.

`os.system('ffmpeg -i {} -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 {}.wav'.format(filename, actual_filename))`

Comment: This works!!! Thanks you:) 
But if I want to redirect all the converted wav files to  different folder, can I add the path in the same ffmpeg command?

 assuming, I have stored the path in "outdir" variable as I have stored "inputdir" in my above code.

Comment: You should be able to do ```os.system('ffmpeg -i {} -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 {}/{}.wav'.format(filename, outdir, actual_filename))```

Hope that helps :)